# Problem in creating alias, get strange messages

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

[Reviewers: note that the question was completely rewritten after the close votes.]

I recently found how I can define aliases for bash in the `~/.bashrc`.

But since I tried that, I see the followig messages eveery time I open a terminal.

I added some bash aliases to my I was trying to create shortcuts using alias but I unsuccessful and somehow managed to get the message below every time I open up a new terminal.

```
bash: alias: UIC: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: sudo openvpn --config ~/vpn/UIC-alopez78.ovpn: not found
bash: alias: mat: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: cd /home/alexisblopez/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/: not found
bash: alias: lab: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: ./matlab: not found
~$
```

Its's confusing; it does not say error, but because my aliases do not work,
I think I did something wrong with them - I don't know what!

Comment: Please specify how you are creating alias in question  ?

Comment: It is also usually suggest that you rather create the aliases in the `~/.bash_aliases` file (create it if it does not exist) just to keep things tidy.

Comment: Good idea - but you should suggest to source `~/.bash_aliases` in `~/.bashrc`. The file is not part of the standard bash startup files.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel At least on recent versions of Ubuntu, the default `.bashrc` does check for `.bash_aliases` and sources it if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you defined these [**alias**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/alias.1posix.html) in `.bashrc` file:

```
alias UIC = 'sudo openvpn --config ~/vpn/UIC-alopez78.ovpn'
alias mat = 'cd /home/alexisblopez/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/'
alias lab = './matlab'
```

You should edit `.bashrc` and remove space before and after `=`:

```
alias UIC='sudo openvpn --config ~/vpn/UIC-alopez78.ovpn'
alias mat='cd /home/alexisblopez/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/'
alias lab='./matlab'
```

save your changes and run `source .bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

The error messages look interesting.
The lines

```
bash: alias: =: not found
```

that is: `bash` gives us the message that it's builtin command, `alias`, gave it the message "not found" for something named `"="`.

Now, `alias` is involved, and there is a `=` in a place where it is mistaken for a command. For the `=` to be treated as a command, it must be a single word, with spaces.

And looking at the syntax of the command `alias` (see `help alias` below), that's wrong:
The `=` must be used without spaces around,, like this:

```
alias foo='bar baz'
```

So, the idea is that there are alias definitions that have extra space around `=`, which separates the one command line argument of `alias` into three arguments.

Let's make an experiment: Can we replicate your error message like this?

```
$ alias mat = 'foo bar'
bash: alias: mat: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: foo bar: not found
```

Yes!

The alias builtin command tries to show the definitions of the three aliases `mat`, `=`, and `foo bar`, as requested, and complains not to find them.

Solution: read `help alias`, find the alias definitions, and remove the space around the `=`.

```
$ help alias
alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
    Define or display aliases.

    Without arguments, `alias' prints the list of aliases in the reusable
    form `alias NAME=VALUE' on standard output.

    Otherwise, an alias is defined for each NAME whose VALUE is given.
    A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
    alias substitution when the alias is expanded.

    Options:
      -p        Print all defined aliases in a reusable format

    Exit Status:
    alias returns true unless a NAME is supplied for which no alias has been
    defined.
```